# Book of revelation what is wormwood?

Tags: revelation

Revelation 8:11 And the name of the star is called WORMWOOD: and the third part of the waters became WORMWOOD; and many men died of the waters, because they were made bitter.

Deuteronomy 29:18 So that there will not be among you a man or woman, or family or tribe, whose HEART turns away today from the LORD our God, to go and serve the gods of those nations; that there will not be among you a root bearing poisonous fruit and WORMWOOD.

I suppose what I am asking is are we the waters stated in revelation 8:11?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqcIYFamnrc there is a link to the video I watched about wormwood.  Something else too Matthew 13:8 But other fell into good ground, and brought forth fruit, some an hundredfold, some sixtyfold, some thirtyfold. Bring forth Fruit.  hope this makes sense. Something else too Matthew 13:8 But other fell into good ground, and brought forth fruit, some an hundredfold, some sixtyfold, some thirtyfold. So if Jesus is talking about fruit then that must mean us (people) right. Hope i am wording this right.

Comment: Your last paragraph appears to be a different question, I will provide an answer to the title and the first two paragraphs. I'd advise you to post the last paragraph as another question.

Comment: Some weeds should just grow so that the wheat is not ruined.

Comment: "See to it that no one misses the grace of God and that no bitter root grows up to cause trouble and defile many" (He 12:15 NASB). Not everything will be sweetness and light in a local church, but unresolved conflict, unforgiveness, and unwillingness to confront can cause the bitter root to grow. To change metaphors, unresolved issues are like an untreated infection, which can get worse and worse. Even a "sharp disagreement" can occur, as in the case of John Mark's deserting Paul during a mission trip. Years later, however, Paul referred to John Mark as "useful to me" (2 Tim 4:11).

Comment: Ironically, look at this history of absinthe which is made from wormwood.

Answer (score 1):

Wormwood is an angel/star from the book of Revelation. The name wormwood is a pun on a Hebrew saying: the name means curse or cursed (and can arguably be traced back to a bitter-tasting plant) and so Wormwood enacts curses in the book of Revelation however, where this occurs in the Old Testament it is almost certainly referring to a curse or to a "cursed" plant with a bitter taste.

Comment: Your answer leaves out a lot which helps in understanding the term and my answer is intended to elaborate and not deny your answer.

Comment: I tend to err on the side of providing a short answer where I am certain of all the facts but I don't get as much detail in, your answers err on the side of providing more detail but at the expense of including more that is a matter of debate. I think there's value in both approaches.

Comment: Certainly there is merit in both, perhaps the better answer though is somewhere in between the two with giving some areas for further research.

Answer (score 1):

According to Smith's Bible dictionary:

> Wormwood. Four kinds of wormwood are found in Palestine -- Artemisia nilotica, Artemisia Judaica, Artemisia fructicosa and Artemisia cinerea. The word occurs frequently in the Bible, and generally in a metaphorical sense.
>   In Jer_9:15; Jer_23:15; Lam_3:15; Lam_3:19, wormwood is symbolical of bitter calamity and sorrow; unrighteous judges are said to "turn judgment to wormwood." Amo_5:7 The Orientals typified sorrows, cruelties and calamities of any kind by plants of a poisonous or bitter nature.

In answer to your specific question regarding:

> Revelation 8:11 And the name of the star is called WORMWOOD: and the third part of the waters became WORMWOOD; and many men died of the waters, because they were made bitter.

the word is used metaphorically for the water becoming poisonous so that mankind died when they drank from third part of the waters.

Regarding:

> Deuteronomy 29:18 So that there will not be among you a man or woman, or family or tribe, whose HEART turns away today from the LORD our God, to go and serve the gods of those nations; that there will not be among you a root bearing poisonous fruit and WORMWOOD.

The word is also used metaphorically to indicate that worshiping false gods leads to destruction, which happened in the book of Joshua, when they ignored God's warning. It is also worth the time and effort to study those other instances mentioned by Smith to better understand what **Wormwood** means in it's various uses in the Bible.

This is of course from my study as a Southern Baptist of the New King James translation.

Hope this helps

Comment: In the beginning of Revelation, several congregations are tolerating invasive non-christian teachings, with a warning that their lamp-stand would be removed. Each congregation, further, was symbolized with an angel (a star). 

Thus its slightly implied that a ***star*** falling from heaven (called wormwood) burning as a ***lamp*** (ie, a congregation) was rejected from their heavenly calling based on their continuance of tolerating unchristian teachings. When they are spit back to the earth, they are brought back to complete their wicked works.